# <md-button> not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have the following code:

```
  <md-list-item ng-repeat="it in mc.items">

      <md-button class="md-button" ng-click="mc.selectItem(it)" ng-class="{'selected' : it === mc.selected }">
        <a ng-href="#/{{it.link}}" >
        <md-icon md-svg-icon="{{it.icon}}" class="menu-icon"></md-icon>
        <span class="menu-item-name">{{it.name}}</span>
        </a>
      </md-button>

  </md-list-item>
```

it works on both Safari & Chrome. However, not on Firefox. When I replace those  tags with  it works, but that creates other problems (eg, button animations stop working, etc.)

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I have latest version of FF,Chrome,Safari & also latest versions of angular. Any help appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Did you find `<a>` as a child of `<md-button>` in [documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/button) ?

Comment: Thank you, I've removed the <a> tag and moved ng-href in to the <md-button>. Works now!

Comment: Glad to help you.. Consider closing this question as __"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error."__

Answer (score 0):

This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.